# Django Rest Mocking a Get request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a viewset for services and an action method defined as:

```
@action(
        methods=['patch'], detail=True, url_name='deploy', url_path='deploy')
    def deploy(self, request, pk=None):
        """
        An extra action for processing requests
        """
        # Gets current instance
        instance = self.get_object()

        [...]

        # Sends GET request 
        get = APIServiceRequestRouter()
        item_list = get.get_data_request()
```

My get_data_request() method will send a get request to a url, which will return a json response.  But of course, this goes out to a third-party api, which I want to mock in my unit test.

I have this unit test for my deploy action endpoint on my services viewset, which currently only test the send of a patch payload to the endpoint.  So I need to add a mocked get response as well:

```
def test_valid_deploy(self) -> None:
        """Test an valid deploy"""
        mock_request
        response = self.client.patch(
            reverse('services-deploy', kwargs={'pk': self.service2.pk}),
            data=json.dumps(self.deploy_payload),
            content_type='application/json'
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_206_PARTIAL_CONTENT)
```

What I'm not sure is how to add a mocked get response into this unit test.  The error I'm getting when I run my unit tests is that in my test_valid_deploy is that the get_data_request() method I have this:

```
response = http_get_request.delay(api_url)
response_obj = response.get()

item_ids = response_obj['item_id']
```

But of course response_obj is empty or of NoneType and therefore the ['item_id'] key does not exist, I get a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` error.

My thoughts then turned to mocking the get to populate response_obj with relevant data so that my test passes.

Any thoughts or help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mocking the return value of `get_data_request` instead?

```py
@mock.patch('path.to.APIServiceRequestRouter.get_data_request')
def test_valid_deploy(self, mocked_get_data_request):
    mocked_get_data_request.return_value = {"key": "value"}  # your mocked object here
    # rest of the test...
```

Comment: Thanks Kedar.  That works a treat.  I have noticed that in mocking my get_data_request() method that it no longer gets coverage as coverage reports that its lines of codes are missing.  I guess that is the trade off with mocking.

Comment: Hi @kedar, how would ensure that my mocked_get_data_request is covered under coverage so that my code is not missed?

Comment: If you're talking about the original `get_data_request` then it will not be covered (since it isn't being called in the test). To solve this, you will need to go deeper and mock the line/call within `get_data_request` that actually makes the HTTP/API call.